# amazon kinesis from pig script

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-kinesis

How can I pull data from a kinesis stream using a pig script locally.

I noticed this example from the amazon documentation but not sure how to import the amazon kinesis pig libraries and the example seems incomplete.  Where do I set the credentials, where can I get the jar for the kinesis library... etc...  Their example is from a grunt-shell, but how would I run it locally from my own machine?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/kinesis-pig-generate-data.html

```
REGISTER ./lib/piggybank.jar;

DEFINE EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT();
DEFINE REGEX_EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.RegexExtract();

raw_logs = load 'AccessLogStream' using com.amazon.emr.kinesis.pig.KinesisStreamLoader('kinesis.iteration.timeout=1') as (line:chararray);

DUMP raw_logs
```

Comment: In the tutorial, the credentials are provided by the IAM role assigned to the EMR custer which allows it access to other AWS resources (set up in a previous step in the tutorial to the link). The JAR is included on the EMR cluster as part of the included Pig libraries. This tutorial is not designed to help you run Pig locally, which would not be trivial in this situation given that you need to access these external AWS services. I'd suggest just running it on EMR, with spot instances if you want to reduce cost.